# What should be validation strategy?

Tags: r, logistic, classification, cross-validation, validation

I am building CTR(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click-through_rate)
Click prediction model with different (61) variables.Dependent variable is weather 0/1( click).I have build logistic regression model and getting probabilities of click for different combination of independent variable.

I am confused about model validation-

1)  What are the parameters should I use for model validation?

2) I am not classifying anything but using classification model for click through rate prediction so using Pseudo R square/ likelihood ration would work?

3) Is there any strategy that I can use for model validation?

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you are not using classification, which would be arbitrary and information-losing.  There are many statistics you can use in logistic model validation.  The most important one to start with is a nonparametric high-resolution calibration curve to check absolute accuracy of probability estimates.  I describe logistic model validation in detail in my book *Regression Modeling Strategies* and its online [course notes](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms).